# Select CSV files and read in pairs

Tags: r

I am comparing two pairs of csv files each at a time. The files I have each end with a number like *cars_file2.csv*, *Lorries_file3.csv*, *computers_file4.csv*, *phones_file5.csv*. I have like 70 files per folder and the way I am comparing is, I compare *cars_file2.csv* and *Lorries_file3.csv* then  *Lorries_file3.csv* and 
*computers_file4.csv*, and the pattern is *2,3,3,4,4,5* like that. Is there a smart way I can handle this instead of manually coming back and change file like the way I am reading here or I can use the last number on each csv to read them smartly. **NOTE** the files have same suffixes *_file*:

```
library(daff)

setwd("path")

# Load csvs to compare into data frames
x_original <- read.csv("cars_file2.csv", strip.white=TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

x_changed <- read.csv("Lorries_file3.csv", strip.white=TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

render(diff_data(x_original,x_changed ,ignore_whitespace=TRUE,count_like_a_spreadsheet = FALSE))
```

My intention is to compare each two pairs of csv and recorded, Field additions, deletions and modified

Comment: are the file name "prefixes" the same for each file of each type (I mean "computers_file*" and "Lorries_file*")? Then it would easy to strip this prefix and order the remaining numbers after converting them into a number)...

Comment: @-R Yoda yes they have same prefixes

Comment: just to be sure: The prefix can be ignored, just the number is relevant to identify the two files to be compared? And: Are there duplicated numbers if I remove the prefixes?

Comment: Yes the prefixes can be ignored and also we don't have duplicated numbers, I have a count of about 70 files

Comment: Are the number in sequence (without gaps)?

Comment: yes they are in sequence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to load all files at once and do your comparison with a full list of files.
This may help:

```
# your path
path <- "insert your path"

# get folders in this path
dir_data <- as.list(list.dirs(path))

# get all filenames
dir_data <- lapply(dir_data,function(x){

  # list of folders
  files <- list.files(x)
  files <- paste(x,files,sep="/")

  # only .csv files
  files <- files[substring(files,nchar(files)-3,nchar(files)) %in% ".csv"]

  # remove possible errors
  files <- files[!is.na(files)]

  # save if there are files
  if(length(files) >= 1){
    return(files)  
  }
})

# delete NULL-values
dir_data <- compact(dir_data)

# make it a named vector
dir_data <- unique(unlist(dir_data))
names(dir_data) <- sub(pattern = "(.*)\\..*$", replacement = "\\1", basename(dir_data))
names(dir_data) <- as.numeric(substring(names(dir_data),nchar(names(dir_data)),nchar(names(dir_data))))

# remove possible NULL-values
dir_data <- dir_data[!is.na(names(dir_data))]

# make it a list again
dir_data <- as.list(dir_data)

# load data
data_upload <- lapply(dir_data,function(x){
  if(file.exists(x)){
    data <- read.csv(x,header=T,sep=";")
  }else{
    data <- "file not found"
  }
  return(data)
})

# setup for comparison
diffs <- lapply(as.character(sort(as.numeric(names(data_upload)))),function(x){

  # check if the second dataset exists
  if(as.character(as.numeric(x)+1) %in% names(data_upload)){

    # first dataset
    print(data_upload[[x]])

    # second dataset
    print(data_upload[[as.character(as.numeric(x)+1)]])

    # do your operations here
    comparison <- render(diff_data(data_upload[[x]],
                     data_upload[[as.character(as.numeric(x)+1)]],
                     ignore_whitespace=T,count_like_a_spreadsheet = F))
    numbers <- c(x, as.numeric(x)+1)

    # save both the comparison data and the numbers of the datasets
    return(list(comparison,numbers))

  }
})

# you can find the differences here
diffs
```

This script loads all csv-files in a folder and its sub-folders and puts them into a list by their numbers. In case there are no doubles, this will work. If you have doubles, you will have to adjust the part where the vector is named so that you can index the full names of the files afterwards.

Comment: how can perform comparisons now after having all this together

Comment: Just insert the ´render()´ call into the last ´lapply()´ statement. Instead of your ´x_original´ variable use the first dataset and for your ´x_changed´ the second one. However, you may want to make sure that R doesn't continue with comparing beyond your last dataset, throwing an error. So you may an if-statement for this. You'll not need the ´print()´ calls. Those are just to show you if you're targeting the right datasets. See my edit.

Comment: Thanks man just last concern how can I know the pair that got compared, just for the same of saving my results for analysis coz the pattern of comparing is first with second then second with third file

Comment: I made an edit to my post. First, I ordered the comparisons in the `lapply()` call so that you can be sure that they are in the right sequence. Now you also receive the differences as well as the numbers of the datasets, which are compared, stored in the same list.

Comment: trying to view the numbers but seems I cant figure it out

Comment: diffs should be a list of lists. It's always comparison and numbers, comparison and numbers etc. When viewing `diffs` you should always get a large output for the differences, followed up by a very small one-liner containing two numbers.

Answer (score 1):

A simple `for`- loop using `paste` will read-in the pairs:

```
for (i in 1:70) { # assuming the last pair is cars_file70.csv and Lorries_file71.csv
  x_original <- read.csv(paste0("cars_file",i,".csv"), strip.white=TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  x_changed <- read.csv(paste0("Lorries_file3",i+1,".csv"), strip.white=TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  render(diff_data(x_original,x_changed ,ignore_whitespace=TRUE,count_like_a_spreadsheet = FALSE))
}
```

Comment: How can I store every pair compared for further analysis if code for  saving is write_diff(). I need  differences saved

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity I used 2 .csv files.

csv_1

```
1,2,4
```

csv_2

```
1,8,10
```

Load all the .csv files from folder,

```
files <- dir("Your folder path", pattern = '\\.csv', full.names = TRUE)
tables <- lapply(files, read.csv)

#create empty list to store comparison output
diff <- c()
```

Loop through all loaded files and compare,

```
for (pos in 1:length(csv)) {
  if (pos != length(csv)) { #ignore last one
    #save comparison output
    diff[[pos]] <- diff_data(as.data.frame(csv[pos]), as.data.frame(csv[pos + 1]), ignore_whitespace=TRUE,count_like_a_spreadsheet = FALSE)
  }
}
```

Compared output by `diff`

```
[[1]]
Daff Comparison: ‘as.data.frame(tables[pos])’ vs. ‘as.data.frame(tables[pos + 1])’ 
      +++ +++ --- ---
@@ X1 X8  X10 X2  X4
```

Comment: How can I know the pair that got compared, like which csv compared, just for the sake of me saving results

Comment: You can print the diff, according to my example (csv_2 with csv_1, csv_3 with csv_2, csv_3 with csv_4)

Comment: what does list one mean now coz i am juts seeing csv_2 csv_3 and csv_1 in list one

Comment: I've updated the answer now it will be more clear for you 1 is common so you cannot see any change but in other numbers you can see the change